# Replace DIVs with certain class based on content of DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I have some DIVs with text, like so:

```
<div class="testclass"><b><i>1 Banana<i></b></div>
<div class="testclass"><b><i>2 Oranges<i></b></div>
<div class="testclass"><b><i>2 Peaches<i></b></div>
<div class="testclass"><b><i>1 Watermelons<i></b></div>
<div class="testclass"><b><i>1 Dragon Fruit<i></b></div>
```

I'm attempting to grab the text in each testclass and create a list, like so:

```
    Banana
    Oranges
    Oranges
    Peaches
    Peaches
    Watermelons
```

What I'm struggling with is replacing the numbers with either nothing, or inserting a new entry into the list with a duplicate.

What I have so far is below:

```
var fruits = $('.testclass').text();
fruits.replace(/1 /,"") ;
```

This gives me a list like the following:

```
Banana
2 Oranges
2 Peaches
1 Watermelons
```

I'm fairly new to jQuery, so I have no clue how to properly iterate through the list or how to properly duplicate entries with 2 in front of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var fruits = [];
$('.testclass').each(function(i, el) {
    var values = $(this).text().split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < values[0]; i++) {
        fruits.push(values[1]);
    }
});
```

Output:

```
["Banana", "Oranges", "Oranges", "Peaches", "Peaches", "Watermelons"]
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/X7jnw/)

---

To cater for fruits with spaces in the name, for example `Dragon fruit`, try this:

```
var fruits = [];
$('.testclass').each(function(i, el) {
    var values = $(this).text().split(' ');
    var count = parseInt(values.shift(), 10);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        fruits.push(values.join(' '));
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/X7jnw/2/)

Comment: What about fruits with spaces in between them? For example, "Dragon fruit".

Comment: I'd imagine you need use `join` with a separator: `var blob = new Blob(fruits.join(','), {type: "text/plain"});`

Comment: This causes it to fail with `TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': The 1st argument is neither an array, nor does it have indexed properties. `

Comment: I don't know what the `Blob` object is, I guess some plugin you're using? I would suggest starting a new question for that.

Comment: I am using chrome, which now natively supports creating data Blobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
.replace(/[0-9]/g,'').trim()
```

`/[0-9]/g` will replace all numbers with an empty string. Then here I've used `.trim()` to remove trailing whitespace. You'll also need to iterate through each `.testclass` using `.each()`:

```
$('.testclass').each(function() {
    $(this).text(function() {
        return $(this).text().replace(/[0-9]/g,'').trim()    
    })
});
```

Comment: I m already doing this, and it does not solve either of my issues as far as duplicating entries with 2 in front of them, or replacing the entirety of the list (as opposed to just the first element).

Comment: `'2 oranges'.replace(/[0-9]/g,'').trim() === 'oranges'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
testclass.replace(/[0-9 ]+/,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('.testclass').each(function() {
    $(this).text(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text().replace(/\d/g,''))    
    })
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b7Eq8/)**

Comment: This is good. I still need instances with 2 in front of them to turn from
`2 Oranges`
into
`Oranges`
`Oranges`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
some_fruits = []
    $('.testclass').each(function(){
        var regex = /\d+/;
        if ($(this).text().match(regex)) {
            str = $(this).text().replace(regex, " ");
            some_fruits.push(str)
        }

    });
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/mt4nz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I am used split ()

```
$(".testclass").each(function(){
    var txt=$(this).text();
    alert(txt.split(' ')[1])


})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74nPW/